# Camera NoiIR camera wont work while my touchscreen is plugged in

Tags: pi-3, camera, touchscreen

I've got a raspberry pi V3. A touchscreen that connects to the DSI port and a Pi NoIR camera module and running the latest lite image. The touchscreen is a non-pi brand screen i found on amazon. It's the "OSOYOO 5 Inch DSI Touch Sceen LCD Display"

When I don't have the screen plugged in, the camera functions as it should. Once i plug in the screen, the camera stops functioning correctly.

running

```
raspistill -t 1000
```

i get this error

```
mmal: mmal_vc_component_enable: failed to enable component: ENOSPC
mmal: camera component couldn't be enabled
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Failed to run camera app. Please check for firmware updates
```

running

```
$ vcgencmd get_camera
```

shows that it is detected

```
supported=1 detected=1
```

things i've tried

- 3 amp power supply directly to the gpio pins
- Updating to latest stable firmware
- Updating to bleeding edge firmware
- A second raspberry pi
- Setting gpu mem to 144
- adding bcm2708.w1_gpio_pin=18 to my config.txt

  While both are plugged in my screen works 100%. Good picture no artifacts and touch works great. It's just that the camera wont work.

  Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out my camera ribbon cable was too long. It worked with the long cable with out the screen, but not with it.

I shortened it to the length I actually needed. Used a small file to reveal the contacts then added a backing so it would seat nicely.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.